# not a trusted location for visual studio project?

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, clr

I'm running visual studio 2015 on a virtual machine and I have problems running CLR projects on it.
the error say: The project location is not of sufficient confidence for the CLR runtime.
what can I do to solve this?
thanks.